# Why do 802.11 Acknowledgement Frames have no source MAC?

Tags: wifi

Anyone know why 802.11 Acknowledgement Frames have no source MAC address?  I don't see it when I capture the packets from TCPDUMP or Wireshark from Linux with a monitor-mode and promiscuous-mode driver. How does the Access Point distinguish ACK frames from different 802.11 clients if there is no source MAC addresses in the frame?

I can see from all the captures that the ACK comes immediately after the frame is sent (around 10 to 30 microseconds) but that alone can't be enough to distinguish the source can it?  Maybe each frame has some kind of unique identifier and the ACK frame has this ID inside it?  Maybe there is identifying information in the encrypted payload since the WLAN uses WPA-PSK mode?

Comment: this isn't really a programming question. you will probably have better luck over at serverfault.com it's the stackexchange site for networking related questions.

Comment: Instead of SF maybe could also use the more specific http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com or http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11):

No, there is nothing encripted in 802.11 MAC ACK frames.

802.11 is a contention based protocol. ie the medium is shared by different STA's and AP's who all are working in the same channel [frequency] in terms of time. Those who wants to transmit are competing for medium , winner who  gets medium starts transmitting.

As per 802.11 spec. , once a frame is on air, the next "SIFS" period medium should be free. ie no one is allowed to transmit. 
At the end of SIFS, the reciever of unicast frame should transmit ACK. This is the rule.

SIFS [Short Interframe space] in 802.11 is ~10 microseconds for OFDM based 802.11 implementations [802.11 G,A]. For 802.11b its ~20 microseconds  if my memory is correct. Thats why you are seeing 10 or 30 microseconds in between TX and ACK

So, everyone knows who is transmitting the ACK and whom the ACK is to. So no need to include source address, its implecit.

Why Source address not included?
To reduce the frame size and so to same power.

Hope it helps. If you got more questions on this, please feel free

Answer (score 2):

ACK frames, like all 802.11 management frames, have a DA (Destination Address) and SA (Source Address) in their MAC header (both not to be exactly confused with just "MAC address, see below), and that's all what's needed in this context.

**TLD;DR: In 802.11 context, "MAC address", SA (Source addr), TA (Transmitter addr), DA (Destination addr), BSSID or whatnot all look alike a 6 byte "MAC address" that we're familiar with from other technologies, yet they should not be confused.**

And now for the demolition of "MAC address" concept in 802.11 context.

802.11 Acknowledgement Frames are parts of 802.11 managements frames, and 802.11 is "a set of media access control (MAC) and physical layer (PHY) specifications" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)).

What this mean - *and this is a very important concept to grasp when working with Wi-Fi* - is that 802.11 in itself, including its management frames, have nothing to do with "traditional" (say 802.3, aka Ethernet) PHY (layer 1) nor MAC (layer 2) layers - they are a kind of their own.

802.3/Ethernet, to continue with this analogy - or rather counter example - have no such thing as ACK frames, beacons, probe request, RTS/CTS, auth/deauth, association etc, which are all types of 802.11 management frames. These are simply not needed with 802.3, for the most part because wired Ethernet is not *a shared media* (that's IEEE terminology), that may lead to unreliability/collision as is air with 802.11/Wi-Fi.

**The important consequence of this is that you should not expect *a priori* to meet other, more familiar concept nor data from other layer 1/2 technologies.** Forget this, once for all.

Sure, Wi-Fi looks like it carry on some MAC and IP and TCP and or UDP or whatnot, and they do most of the time, but regarding management frames such as ACK, that's a different world - its own world. As it is, 802.11 could perfectly be used - and maybe is used in some niche use cases - to carry other higher level protocols than TCP/IP. And its MAC concept, though looking familiar with its 6 bytes, should not be confused in its form nor use to the MAC of 802.3/Ethernet. To take another example, 802.15 aka Bluetooth also have a 6 bytes MAC, yet that is again another thing.

And to take the 802.11 *a contrario* example, 802.11 layer 1/2 beacon frames for instance carry some info about SSID, supported rates, Frequency-hopping (FH), parameter set etc etc that have no counterparts in other L1/2 technologies.

Now, embrace the complexity of what is/are "MAC addresses" in 802.11...

And this is why, to take an example in day to day use, [`pcap`/`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) have such weird filters such as `wlan ra`, `wlan ta`, `wlan addr1`, `wlan addr2`, `wlan addr3`, `wlan addr4` - and the like for `wireshark` capture and display filter.

Answer (score 0):

Right George..!!

In MAC format NAV timer is updated like that, while data frames NAV is updated while transmitting , It updates for

DATA frame + SIFS + ACK + SIFS

So there is clear for this time, only one AP <---> station is talking, all are waiting to be clear NAV time period, so doesn't need to add Source address as it is wasting frame bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same question and saw this stackoverflow question on internet.

If you think about it, if stationA is waiting for ack from stationB, that means stationA has pretty much secured/locked medium for that long (see Jaydeep's answer) time i.e. (enough time for 2SIFS + 1ACK assuming no follow-up transmission between these 2 stations).

Hence no other station is sending any frame (i.e. ack here), leading no need to distinguish ack.

Its just StationA is waiting for ack from stationB in that time window.